# Adding the comment child to the data structure of a post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a data structure for my social media app that should look something like this:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-Lhg9lSr1ztxtawJ0oBV" : {
      "reports" : 0,
      "text" : "Let’s try reports",
      "timestamp" : 1560887892027,
      "title" : "Fine\t",
      "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      "comments" : {
           "reports" : 0,
           "text" : "Let’s try reports",
           "timestamp" : 1560887892027,
           "title" : "Fine\t",
           "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhd1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
    }
  }
}
```

But at the moment, my JSON has no comment section. This is the code I am using for submitting my post:

```
   let postObject = [
        "title": titleText.text,
        "text": mainText.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"],
        "userID": userID,
        "reports": 0,
        "comments": []
    ] as [String : Any]


    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.delegate?.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }  else {
                    // Handle error

        }
    }
```

You add comments to posts by clicking on a displyed post in a table cell which takes you to the MainTextView filled with that post's information. There, you can type your comment and then hit the reply button which should add your comment to the post. The function I am using to this end is the following:

```
Database.database().reference().childByAutoId().child( newCommentLabel.text)
```

Eventually, I would very much like to add the data structure described above to my comments as well. But right now, even just trying to add a comment does nothing for my database. After reading the Firebase documentation, I am a bit confused about how to adapt my code so that it creates the appropriate data structure. Let me know if you need to see additional details. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add comment you need

```
let comment:[String:Any] = [ "reports" : 0,
       "text" : "Let’s try reports",
       "timestamp" : 1560887892027,
       "title" : "Fine\t",
       "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhd1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
] 
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("posts/\(postId)/comments").childByAutoId().setValue(comment)
```

when you edit a post to add a comment sure you need to have it's `postId`

Comment: It worked as:  let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("posts/\(post!.id)/comments").childByAutoId().setValue(newCommentLabel.text!)